# How to test ElasticSearch in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, elasticsearch

I want to know about spring + java + elasticsearch's setting way
This is my code, but the following error occurred.

[This java code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q31OG.png)

[This pom.xml part of elasticsearch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3mHg.png)

------- this stack console error -------

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_31  at
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharacterUtils.getInstance(CharacterUtils.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArrayMap.(CharArrayMap.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArrayMap$EmptyCharArrayMap.(CharArrayMap.java:659)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArrayMap.(CharArrayMap.java:55)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArraySet.(CharArraySet.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.StopAnalyzer.(StopAnalyzer.java:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer.(StandardAnalyzer.java:64)
>     at org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.Lucene.(Lucene.java:71)
>     at org.elasticsearch.Version.fromId(Version.java:528)   at
>   org.elasticsearch.Version.fromString(Version.java:591)    at
>   org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginInfo.readFromProperties(PluginInfo.java:116)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.getModuleBundles(PluginsService.java:335)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.(PluginsService.java:114)
>     at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:146)    at
>   org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:128)     at
>   org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:145)    at
>   dev.mountaingo.kr.elasticsearch.ElasticNode.(ElasticNode.java:25)
>     at
>   dev.mountaingo.kr.elasticsearch.ElasticNode.main(ElasticNode.java:51)

Comment: Post code, not screenshot.

Comment: So, is it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch 2.2.1 uses Lucene 5.4.1, so in this case it's most probably a versioning problem. Try version 5.4.1 for lucene-analyzers-common.

Comment: Thnk you very very much ! I try it